# How to sort a table by joined column?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

How can i sort a table by joined column?
I can only sort by column that is selected by "FROM".

My full query:

```
SELECT rp.'data', ra.'data2', rgl.'data3' FROM 'rp_table' rp 
JOIN 'ra_table' ra ON rp.'Id' = ra.'pruefungsId' 
JOIN 'rgl_table' rgl ON rp.'uId' = rgl.'Id' 
ORDER BY rp.'data', rgl.'data3' DESC
```

Order by 'data' works, order by 'data3' doesn´t work.

Any ideas how to sort by join column?

Comment: You appear to be using single quotes when  you should be using backticks 'I can only sort by column that is selected by "FROM".' - not true.

Comment: Shouldn't it work without any quotes at all?

Comment: Yes, but it´s not the matter here ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think order by 'data3' is not working because it is from one of the joined tables.

To confirm this you can try the below scenarios:

1. Try sorting using data3 first and then data and see how that works
2. Try sorting using two different columns in the rp_table and see how that works

It would be helpful to better answer your question, if you could please share the outcome you are expecting and the actual outcome you are getting.

Also, could you please confirm if you want to sort both the columns in descending order or first column in ascending order and second one in descending?

Comment: 1) I tried that and only sort by data3, but nothing changes, it seems like sort by data3 doesn´t work.

Comment: 2) Sorting by other parameters from rp_table work, but not rgl_table.

Comment: @ChristianStegemann, Would you please be able to share the expected and actual outcome? I have tried the scenario in sample tables and sorting is working even if the column is from joined table.